# How to resolve a git remote?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, git

Suppose the following configuration:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
Host foo
HostName git.foo.com
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/foo
Port 9000
User git
$ cd WORKING_COPY
$ git remote -v
origin  foo:bla.git (fetch)
origin  foo:bla.git (push)
```

What git subcommand can I use, inside the `WORKING_COPY` folder, to resolve the real URL of the `origin` remote (i.e. `git+ssh://git@git.foo.com:9000/bla.git`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Git is concerned, that *is* the real URL. `git remote -v` and `git remote get-url` only perform substitutions defined in Git's own configuration (i.e. the `url.*.insteadOf` settings). The rest is passed directly to the SSH client.

Therefore, you'll need to either parse `~/.ssh/config` yourself, or ask the `ssh` program somehow. Recent OpenSSH versions have the `-G` option for that:

```
$ ssh -G foo | egrep "^(user|hostname|port) "
user git
hostname git.foo.com
port 9000

$ ssh -G foo | perl -e 'while (<>) { /^(\S+) (.*)$/ and $c{$1} = $2; }
                        for ($c{hostname}) { /:/ and s/.*/[$&]/; }
                        print "ssh://$c{user}\@$c{hostname}:$c{port}/\n";'
ssh://git@git.foo.com:9000/
```

<sup>(The `git+ssh://` and `ssh+git://` prefixes are planned for removal from git.)</sup>

For older versions, which don't have a *direct* option for that; you could perhaps abuse its ProxyCommand option (that's what Mosh does), or LocalCommand if you don't mind it actually *connecting* to the server:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand=">&2; echo %h %p" foo
```

Comment: Thanks, but then how do I detect that the remote is an ssh one? `foo:` could be a valid URL scheme, maybe. How how can I list the schemes/protocols the currently-installed `git` understands (so I can assume it's ssh if it's _not_ in that list) ?

Comment: When it comes to git...URL parsing gets a bit weird. Your simplest option might be to assume it's an URL scheme if it's immediately followed by `:/` (nearly all URLs) or `::` (external git-remote-foo handlers), otherwise assume scp style address.

Comment: Thanks! If nobody comes up with a better answer in the next couple days I'll accept this one.

Comment: Oh wait, `host:/path/to/repo` is actually valid. In fact, if you happen to have a server named `http`, then even `http://foo/bar` can be interpreted in both ways. So perhaps assume URL if it has `://`, or even whitelist specific schemes (search git's source code for the list).

Comment: If `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -G >${PWD}/foo" git ls-remote origin xxx` returns with a non-zero return code *and* the file `foo` exists, then the remote used ssh and all the information is available in that file. If it returned a zero return code, then the remote was reached without involving ssh (and so there's nothing to resolve, unless maybe using `/etc/hosts`.